# Route - Laravel Doesn't load for half pages

Tags: php, html, laravel, routes

I'm been having a problem with Laravel. My problem is that i have routes connecting to different web pages but half of the web pages doesn't load and the other have them do. I have PHP pages for each of the pages and have them connected.
I get the 404
Here is my routes

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/index', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/hub','PagesController@hub');
Route::get('/basicmod','PagesController@basicmod');
Route::get('/addquestion','PagesController@addquestion');
Route::get('/introtest','TestController@index');
```

All the routes connect to a function in the page controller or test controller like :

```
public function addquestion(){
    $title = "Add Question";
    return view('pages.addquestion')->with('title',$title);
}
```

Here is the places where i call the functions :

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='http://localhost/microskills/public/hun/'"></button>
<button><a href="http://localhost/microskills/public/questions">Questions</a></button>
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you actually call the routes that are not working?

Comment: calling a url with ".../public/..."  usually means you have a configuration problem. Read the docs to know how to configure apache/nginx/whatever in your server, with laravel.

Comment: Or use `php artisan serve` in your project folder

Comment: you should be able to type php artisan route:list  to get a list of your routes. that may help.  Also are you running php artisan serve or homestead or something else?

Comment: Please list which ones work, and which ones do not work.

Comment: I agree with @FelippeDuarte as well as kerbholz, but also you have a typo in your links. There is no route defined with the url questions in your list, nor is there a route with the url /hun. though I see an /addquestion and a /hub

Comment: You have to use `url('basicmod')` for example.

Comment: it's not the buttons or the links when i type in localhost/skills/public/addquestion it still does the same thing as the button does